# Who is the "possessor of heaven and earth" in Genesis 14:19. Abraham or God?

Tags: genesis, grammar, 1-corinthians, referent-identification, historical-interpretation

Who is the **"possessor of heaven and earth"** in

> **Genesis 14:19** And he blessed him, and said, Blessed be Abram of the
>   most high God, possessor of heaven and earth: 20 and blessed be the
>   most high God, which hath delivered thine enemies into thy hand. ( AKJV )

?

**Is it Abraham or Most High God?**

I have this doubt because there are two **"Blessed"** in the verse about two persons. And

> **1 Corinthians 3:21-22** For **all things are yours,** Whether Paul, or Apollos, or Cephas, or the world, or life, or death, or things
>   present, **or things to come; all are yours;**

states that we possess all things.

I have been thinking of what it means **"death belongs to us"** or **"all things belong to us"**

> **2 Corinthians 6:10** as sorrowful, yet alway rejoicing; as poor, yet
>   making many rich; as having nothing, and **yet possessing all
>   things.**

Scripture says God gave Christ all things ( which should include heaven ) and He became a heir of God.

> **Hebrews 1:2** hath in these last days spoken unto us by his Son, whom he
>   hath **appointed heir of all things**, by whom also he made the
>   worlds;

Again it is written we are **"Heirs of God"** and **Co-heirs with Christ**

> **Romans 8:17**  and **if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and
>   joint-heirs with Christ;** if so be that we suffer with him, that we
>   may be also glorified together.

The promise to Abraham was that he will be the heir of the [Universe](https://biblehub.com/greek/2889.htm).

> **Romans 4:13** “For the promise, that he should be the heir of the [world](https://biblehub.com/greek/2889.htm),
>   was not to Abraham, or to his seed, through the law, but through the
>   righteousness of faith.”

The seed of Abraham is Christ and those in Christ.

> **Galatians 3:16** Now to Abraham and his seed were the promises made. He
>   saith not, And to seeds, as of many; but as of one, And to thy **seed,
>   which is Christ.**
>
> **Galatians 3:29** And if ye be Christ’s, then are **ye Abraham’s seed, and
>   heirs** according to the promise.

**So if Christ inherited *"all things"* which includes *heaven* was Melchizedek prophesying in advance that *Abraham will possess heaven and earth*?**

This brings into view another question "What is heaven?"

If heaven is a created thing then "where did God dwell before He created heaven?"

So is heaven a state of being in God?

A [habitation ( or dwelling place, or Abode )](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4583.htm) **"in God"** as Moses, Jesus & Paul said?

> **Psalm 90:1** A Prayer of Moses, the man of God. Lord, a **habitation** 
>   Thou -- Thou hast been, To us -- in generation and generation, ( YLT )
>
> **John 14:2** In my Father's house there are many **abodes**; were it not so,
>   I had told you: for I go to prepare you a place; ( Darby Bible
>   Translation )
>
> **John 15:4** **Abide** in me, and I in you. As the branch cannot bear fruit
>   of itself, except it abide in the vine; no more can ye, except ye
>   abide in me.
>
> **Ephesians 2:22** in whom you also are being built up together to become a fixed **abode** for God through the Spirit. ( Weymouth new Testament )

of which we now have an inward experience?

An inward experience of the [heavenly things](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=AKJV&quicksearch=heavenly&begin=47&end=73) which produces and outward effect in daily living?

And the one that is experienced in the body also after we receive a heavenly body?

> **1 Corinthians 15:49** and, according as we did bear the image of the earthy, we shall bear also the **image of the heavenly**.
>
> 1 John 3:2 beloved, now, children of God are we, and it was not yet
>   manifested what we shall be, and we have known that if he may be
>   manifested, **like him we shall be**, because we shall see him as he is;
>
> Revelation 21:3 And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying,
>   “Behold, the **dwelling place of God is with man**. He will dwell with
>   them, and they will be his people, and God himself will be with them
>   as their God. ( ESV )
>
> 1 Corinthians 2:9 but, according as it hath been written, **'What eye
>   did not see, and ear did not hear, and upon the heart of man came not
>   up,** what **God did prepare for those loving Him** -- ' ( YLT )

Comment: The sentence קֹנֵ֖ה שָׁמַ֥יִם is correlated in Gen. 14:22. The possessor of the heavens and the earth is אֵ֣ל עֶלְי֔וֹן (Gen. 14:20)

Comment: Melchizedek king of Salem was priest of אֵ֣ל עֶלְי֔וֹן (Gen. 14:18 NET) and this title is in Psalm 78:35 HEBREW and all this is related to θεὸς ὁ ὕψιστος of the verses Gen. 14:18-20, 22; 1 Es. 6:30; 8:19, 21; Jdt. 13:18; Ps. 56:3; 77:35, 56; Dan. 3:93; 5:1; Dat. 3:93; 4:2; 5:18, 21; Mk. 5:7; Lk. 8:28; Acts 16:17; Heb. 7:1.

Comment: "The God, the Most High," was the title by which non-Jews referred to the God of Abraham.

Answer (score 4):

'God' is described in two ways in Genesis 14:19.

- 1) He is 'the most high God, possessor of heaven and earth'
- 2) He is 'the most high God which hath delivered thine enemies into thy hand'.

I know (from your profile and contributions) that English is your second language and I think that your difficulty is just with English construction.

The first statement is a blessing pronounced on Abram by Melchizedek, which blessing will come from God.

- 1) Blessed be Abram ... *of* (or by) ... God.

The second statement is a blessing pronounced toward God by Melchizedek.

- 2) Blessed be God (by the speaker, Melchizedek).

I must confess I do not understand your quoting the 1 Corinthians verse. I do not see the connection, but that may be a lack on my part. If you still have a question, just expand the second part of your question and I will try to assist if I am able.

Comment: Good answer!  Well Explained

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you :-)

Comment: @NijelJ I have expanded as you have directed. Please see if it is clear enough. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the Portuguese translation, NIV and ACF, the possessor is not Abraham, but God. In the portuguese grammatical rule is that the adjective is linked to the closest subject, which in this case is God. The other subject of the sentence, Abraham, is comparatively located far from the adjective "Possessor", so it cannot be him. So it is clear for me that the Portuguese translators understood it in this way: God is the possessor of heaven and earth.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45886)

Answer (score 0):

While Melchizedek's prophetic declaration: "possessor of Heaven and Earth" refers to God most high, however, it is also a powerful prophetic declarative blessing upon Abraham, the faithful and humble servant of the most-high God, whom God is pleased to make his "seed" the heir of all things in Christ Jesus. So it's very correct to say that the passage actually refers to Abraham!

This is one of those mysteries that the carnal mind will never comprehend or understand. How can a mortal man like Abraham be the possessor of Heaven and Earth? Brethren, this is a spiritual thing! Taking a deep discerning look at the strange person blessing Abraham will give us a clue of how weighty and divine those declarative prophetic blessings upon Abraham are. God never lies and His words are Yes and Amen. Abraham through his seed Jesus Christ remains forever the sole possessor of Heaven and Earth. Hallelujah! To God most high be all the glory and honor and thanksgiving in Jesus mighty name, Amen!

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is Abraham that is possessor.....God does not need to possess what He made and created. Instead he has put it up for whoever is capable of to possess And Abraham did through faithful obedience And vision and his unending dedication to God. The second part is the salute to God.

Through Christ, we gentiles have been made partakers  of the blessings of Abraham. Bringing us under his lineage because God had promised him this. And now we are co-heirs with Christ...we too as offspring of Abraham ate now co- possessors of heaven and earth

The earth is our inheritance and when we make heaven, heaven also becomes ours
God lives above his creation

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "Possessor of heaven and earth" is an accolade or designation that the people customarily attached to God when they spoke about Him. It is an accolade that specifies which God is being referred to as against all the idiots that people also worshipped as gods. This is supported by the fact that when Abram also talked about the same God, he also added that accolade or designation "Possessor of heaven and earth". This shows that in this Chapter and context, Abram is not the person being referred to as Possessor of heaven and earth even though in later parts of scripture we can find basis and cause to justify men being referred to as possessors. An example is found in the words of Jesus Christ at the beginning of the Beatitudes in Matthew 5:3, 5:

> <sup>**3**</sup> Blessed are the poor in spirit, For theirs is the kingdom of heaven. ... <sup>**5**</sup> Blessed are the meek, For they shall inherit the earth.

The above shows that there is a sense in which a man can be referred to as Possessor of heaven and earth. But that was not the case in Genesis 14.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.